# I am unable to create a map that has another map inside it

Tags: json, http, flutter, dart, maps

I'm trying to create a sign up model and send it to my API but the "location" Key has another map/jsonobject that contains a "type": "point" and "coordinates": [double, double].

The final json object is supposed to look something like this

```
{
    "name": "Arsh Bansal",
    "email": "ab@yahoo.com",
    "password": "123456789",
    "birthday": "06-21-2000",
    "gender": "Male",
    "location": {
        "type": "Point", 
        "coordinates": [13.0987, 88.403]
    },
    "phone_number": "123456789"
}
```

Network Helper code is below:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class NetworkHelper {

  NetworkHelper(this.url);
  NetworkHelper.withHeader(this.url, this.headers);

  final String url;
  Map<String, String> headers;

  Future getData() async {

    http.Response response = await http.get(url);

    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
      String data = response.body;

      return jsonDecode(data);
    } else {
      String error = response.body;

    }
  }

  Future<http.Response> postData(Map body) async {

    http.Response response = await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: body);
    return response;

  }

}
```

But I get the error below

The error I get is :
*Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, List>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast*

```
#0      CastMap.forEach.<anonymous closure> (dart:_internal/cast.dart:288:25)
#1      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:379:8)
#2      CastMap.forEach (dart:_internal/cast.dart:287:13)
#3      mapToQuery (package:http/src/utils.dart:17:7)
#4      Request.bodyFields= (package:http/src/request.dart:137:12)
#5      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:170:17)
#6      BaseClient.post (package:http/src/base_client.dart:58:7)
#7      post.<anonymous closure> (package:http/http.dart:70:16)
#8      _withClient (package:http/http.dart:166:20)
#9      post (package:http/http.dart:69:5)
#10     NetworkHelper.postData (package:clubinn/services/network_helper.dart:28:36)
#11     Models.createUser (package:clubinn/models/models.dart:72:50)
#12     _SignUpPageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:clubinn/sc<…>
```

Comment: Is that the only part of the error you have? No stacktrace?

Comment: @julemand101 I've added the stack trace to the initial question

Comment: Can you show the class `NetworkHelper` from "package:clubinn/services/network_helper.dart"? Especially the `postData` method. I can't seem to find the package on pub.dev so I guess it is your own?

Comment: @julemand101 I've added the networkHelper class to the initial question

Comment: Can you pls edit the title so that it's more telling? It is very generic now and one has no idea about the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the use of `http.post` and the `body` argument. If you read the documentation you can see it is described as:

> body sets the body of the request. It can be a String, a List or a Map. If it's a String, it's encoded using encoding and used as the body of the request. The content-type of the request will default to "text/plain".
>
> ...
>
> If body is a Map, it's encoded as form fields using encoding. The content-type of the request will be set to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; this cannot be overridden.

https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/post.html

The input `body` your are given comes from the following code:

```
    Map<String, dynamic> body = {
      "name": name,
      "email": email,
      "password": password,
      "birthday": DOB,
      "gender": gender,
      "location": location.toJson(),
      "phone_number": mobile
    };
```

Where the type are not even close to be `Map<String, String>` since e.g. location are given a `Map<String, dynamic>` as value:

```
  Map<String,dynamic> toJson() => {
    "type": type,
    "coordinates": List<double>.from(coordinates.map((x) => x)),
  };
```

Also, I don't think you want to give `body` the Map in the first place. As you can see in the documentation mentioned before, maps are "encoded as form fields using encoding". What you properly want instead is to parse the map into a JSON string and give this string as body to `http.post`.

So it should properly be something like this instead:

```
http.Response response = await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: json.encode(body));
```